# Paypal IPN Unsubscribe, sending out new logins?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I've created a IPN listener on a site and currently it works fine for people subscribing and creates their PIN number, adds to their logins (email and randomly generated PIN) to the DB without issue. They can then login to the download area after getting an email with the details.

The signup works perfectly - however, when they **unsubscribe**, Paypal clearly sends the notificaiton and the IPN is simply issuing new logins and I don't know how to code it to send a "Sorry you're leaving" email and remove them from the DB.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Script below;**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

$email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$password = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES('". mysql_escape_string($email) ."', '".md5($password)."' ) ") or die(mysql_error()); 

$to      = $email;
$subject = 'xxx Download Area | Login credentials';
$message = '

Thank you for your purchase

Your account information
-------------------------
Email: '.$email.'
Password: '.$password.'
-------------------------

You can now login at xxxxx';
$headers = 'From:xxx@xxx.co.uk' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



}

else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

// PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!

$to      = 'paypal@xxx.co.uk';
$subject = 'xxx Download Area | Invalid Payment';
$message = '

Dear xxx,

A payment has been made for the Download area on xxx.co.uk but is flagged as INVALID.
Please verify the payment manually and contact the buyer.

Please contact xxx at xxx on xxx if you need additional help, the buyers email is below;

Buyer Email: '.$email.'
';
$headers = 'From:noreply@xxx.co.uk' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome code! Can you help with mine?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530430/php-paypal-ipn-membership-script-help-needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a switch that checks for the type of txn_type that is sent along with the ipn. This is just off the top of my head but give it a try.....

```
$email = $_POST['payer_email'];               

switch ($_POST['txn_type']) {
          case 'web_accept':
            //you received a payment such as a buy now button
            //so now lets do things such as trigger a call to a 
            //function to create an email or add POST vars to a database
            $this->createUser($email, $password);
            $this->createEmail($email, $password);
          break;
          case 'subscr_signup':
            //This shows that someone has subscribed using a subscribe button
            //We can do anything here such as increase the users access level
          break;
          case 'subscr_payment':
            //payment for a subscribed user has just been made
            //do something such as send them a conformation email
          break;
          case 'subscr_eot':
            //this is a End Of Terms meaning that the subscriber either canceled or
            //paypal could not process the payment due to the user not having the funds
            //lets remove them from our database and send them an email
            $this->removeUser($email);
          break;
    case 'subscr_cancel':
            //Here the user canceled their account so lets remove them and send an email
            $this->removeUser($email);
          break;
        }

       function createEmail($email, $password)
       {

        $to      = $email;               
        $subject = 'xxx Download Area | Login credentials';               
        $message = '               

        Thank you for your purchase               

        Your account information               
        -------------------------               
        Email: '.$email.'               
        Password: '.$password.'               
        -------------------------               

        You can now login at xxxxx';               
        $headers = 'From:xxx@xxx.co.uk' . "\r\n";               

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);               

       }

       function createUser($email, $password)
       {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES('". mysql_escape_string($email) ."', '".md5($password)."' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
       }
```

Something along those lines should atleast get you in the right direction.